# Mathematica help to check a positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, mathematica

I am new to Mathematica and am trying to check if the following matrix is positive definite with the program. The answer is supposed to be yes because $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ but I don't know how to add this into the function.

[image]

I know it is positive definite but I'm trying to use Mathematica to show that it is positive definite.

Comment: Check whether the determinant is positive. The element $(2,2)$ is $=2$ so $>0$, hence  $\det>0$ will be equivalent to positive definite in this case.

Comment: Why post a screenshot instead of ASCII that can be copy-pasted into Mathematica?

Comment: This question would be better for mathematica.stackexchange.com.  For example, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240445/symbolic-real-positive-definite-matrix

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is positive definite. One of several equivalent necessary and sufficient conditions is $q_{22}>0$ and $\det Q>0$.Note that $\det Q=48(x^6+x^2y)$.

Comment: Where is the proof that that determinant is globally positive?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mathematica, copy your equation display right click, copy as LaTeX and paste/post it here between $$\$\$\text{hello}\$\$ $$

$$\text{Eigenvalues}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 8 \left(7 x^6+3 x^2 y\right) & 8 x^3 \\
 8 x^3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]$$

or copy the original straight input with and indent or between {} in the tool bar of the input window

```
 Eigenvalues[({{8 (7 x^6 + 3 x^2 y), 8 x ^3}, {8 x ^3, 2} })]
```

$$ 28 x^6+12 x^2 y-\sqrt{784 x^{12}+672 x^8 y+8 x^6+144 x^4 y^2-24 x^2 y+1}+1$$,
$$28 x^6+12 x^2 y+\sqrt{784 x^{12}+672 x^8 y+8 x^6+144 x^4 y^2-24 x^2 y+1}+1 $$

$$ \det   \left| 
\begin{array}{cc}
 8 \left(7 x^6+3 x^2 y\right) & 8 x^3 \\
 8 x^3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right|  = 48 x^6 + 48 x^2 y
$$

The $y$ term makes the determinant indefinite